# Twilio TwiML response body too large error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twilio

Why I'm getting this error "TwiML response body too large".
I'm try to get the latest call status by adding arguments in Twilio Call like:

```
call = client.account.calls.create({
       :url => used_url,
       :to => to_no, 
       :from => from_no,
       :method => "GET",                              
       :status_callback => "http://xxx/en/update_twilio_call_status",
       :status_callback_method => "POST",
       :status_callback_event => ["initiated", "ringing", "answered", "completed"],
       :if_machine => "Hangup",
       :timeout => "20"
       })
```

And, in my Rails Controller I have this:

```
def update_twilio_call_status
    @job = TwilioCall.where(:twilio_sid => params['CallSid']).first
    @job.twilio_status = params['CallStatus']
    @job.save
    render nothing: true
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

The Twilio error message is explained in more detail here: https://www.twilio.com/docs/errors/11750

It says:

> Possible Causes
>
> - The TwiML that you are serving is larger than 64 kB
> - You are serving non-TwiML in your response

While you don't look like you're serving more than 64kB of TwiML it could be that you're not returning TwiML at all.

Try returning an empty `<Response/>` tag.

Comment: Good day philnash, I'm very new to Twilio. I have question, when adding the arguments like >> [ :status_callback, :status_callback_method , :status_callback_event ]

 My only purpose is to get the latest status posted by Twilio API while call is on-going. Do I need to return  XML response ?

Comment: You know, I wouldn't have thought that was the issue either, was just my first suggestion given the error message. Are you only getting this error on the callback functions? What does the `used_url` do?

Comment: Yes only when adding [status_callback, :status_callback_method , :status_callback_event ] method.  The "used_url" contains the whole XML <Response>.... No issue when not using the above methods. I just want the Twilio API post "CallStatus" when call is on-going for latest update in my GUI.

Comment: Like in this link (Ruby Tab)... https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/making-calls#example-4
. Make a call from 866-867-5309 to 415-555-1212, and POST all the call progress events to url "https://www.myapp.com/events"

Comment: @philnash my response is only 499bytes but still getting this error, any other reasons I might get this error?

Comment: @AbhimanuSharma I'm going to need more context for that question (especially as this answer is from 2015!). Can you ask a new question and let me know what you are doing, sharing code if possible, and how you get this error?

Comment: @philnash I have posted a new question, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71598019/twiml-response-body-too-large-with-php-as-backend