# TwiML response body too large with php as backend

Tags: twilio, twilio-api, twilio-php, twilio-twiml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Response>
    <Gather numDigits='1' timeout='10' action='https://mywebsite.info/application/twilios/welcomegather/100/13333333333/3780' method='GET'>
        <Say>You have a new leed from FirstName LastName phone number 3333333333 Please press 1 to connect to lead.</Say>
    </Gather>
    <Say>We didn't receive any input. Goodbye!</Say>
    <Redirect>https://nywebsite.info/application/twilios/welcomescript1/100/13333333333/3780/1</Redirect>
</Response>
```

Above is my response getting by hitting the api

DEBUG EVENT SID
NO11a11ec9eaf1d68ff213c8df6a98db22

RESOURCE SID
CA3429234af01d9e5cb3271c36e450a76c

Comment: I can't see your Notification, can you post more about the error you are getting. Is there more information in the Twilio error log in your console?

Comment: Also, usually that error means your PHP application crashed and returned a stack trace to Twilio instead of TwiML. Take a look at your application logs when the action URL is hit.